# Dynamics 365 - Plugin - Newly Created Images Are Null when checked in code?

Tags: plugins, crm, dynamics-365

I am working on a d365 unified interface sandbox environment on a development project.
This environment was setup recently as a clone of the production d365 instance.

Today I have been adding some plugins and finding a strange issue. I can get the plugin code on record create/update firing no problem (I have pre operation create/update and post operation create/update stages defined and the correct code gets hit for each).
But the C# plugin code does not recognise any of the pre or post images that I have added.
In code when we check IPluginExecutionContext.PostEntityImages it does not contain anything.

Any of the pre existing images that were there already when the environment was cloned are firing correctly. We have a process whereby we name all of our pre and post images the exact same for every entity and I know the ones I have created are named exactly as expected.
In this example I have created a Post Operation stage Update plugin on the OOB opportunity entity with a PreImage defined against it but the code just will not recognise it.

Anyone experienced this before?
TIA

Comment: Maybe you need a MS support ticket for investigation. This could be one of a issue, I never experienced this strange behavior.

Comment: I too haven't experienced this. If you have not solved it, can you share some screenshots of the images configuration and the code you are using so we might help?

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally the sandbox service seems to fail picking up updates on a plugin assembly. In those cases updating the assembly with a different assembly version (build or revision number) can help.

If not, I would advise to simply remove the complete assembly and recreate it again.

If you do not have an automated deployment process in place, follow these steps:

1. Create a separate solution.
2. Add the assembly along with its step registrations and images to the solution.
3. Export the solution.
4. Remove the assembly using the plugin registration tool.
5. Import the solution again.